# How do I start a MapProxy Instance in the background?

Tags: linux, mapproxy

I use the following command in linux with an "&" hoping to be able to close that putty session but "&" doesn't seem to work with this command :

```
sudo mapproxy-util serve-develop mapproxy.yaml -b 0.0.0.0:8010
```

When I run the above command with an "&" I get the following output (instead of a MapProxy instance startup log) :

> [1] 30354

When I then do a `ps aux | grep 8010` it gives the following result:

> root     30354  0.0  0.1  49252  3488 pts/0    T    15:23   0:00 sudo mapproxy-util serve-develop mapproxy.yaml -b 0.0.0.0:8010

And when I try to access MapProxy demo page it gives:

> "This site can’t be reached"

Comment: `8010` seems to be the port your program is listening at. Do you connect at the correct port? Also you might want to consider using `screen` starting background processes

Comment: Yes, that is the right port I am using, When I start a MapProxy Instance without "&" everything works as expected. Okay, Let me try with 'screen'..

Comment: Thankyou so much nickves, using 'screen' with the command worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the command which worked for me is the following:

screen -L sudo mapproxy-util serve-develop mapproxy.yaml -b 0.0.0.0:8010